# Binary == between 'int' and 'struct member' when both values are int

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs which have an array inside.

```
struct member{
int num;
char name[10];
int m[5];
int counter;
}ptr[10];
```

And i'm trying to type a condition that compares the values of the array inside the struct and the value of the array that contain the structs. When i make a binary comparison i get the error that one is 'int' and the other is a struct member. The struct member is also an int (an array with int value), so why am i getting this problem?

```
void checkiffriends(){
for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j=0; j < 5; j++){
        if(ptr[i].m[j] == ptr[i+1]){
            printf("they are friends!", );
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `ptr[i]` is not an `int`. Simple as that.

Comment: When `i==9`, what is `ptr[i+1]` attempting to reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr[i].m[j] == ptr[i]` was probably meant as `ptr[i].m[j] == i` revealing a flaw in the algorithm.

I'm assuming the `m` array represents the indexes of "I am friend of ..." for that `ptr[i]`. So for a given `ptr[i]`, you want to list all his friends, meaning

- check all *other* `ptr[j]`, `i!=j`, and see if `i` is in the `m` list of that other "person"

Is this assumption correct?

That would lead to something like

```
void checkiffriends(){
   int i,j,k;
   for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
      for(j=0; j < 10; j++){
         if (i != j) {
            for(k=0; k < 5; k++){
               if(ptr[j].m[k] == i){
                  printf("%d is friend of %d\n", j, i); // indexes
                  printf("%s is friend of %s\n", ptr[j].name, ptr[i].name); // names
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct and that is exactly what i was aiming for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are not comparing two ints. You are trying to compare m[j] to the struct it is in. Perhaps you meant ptr[i].num or .counter

Answer (score 1):

`ptr[i]` is a struct. `ptr[i].m[j]` is an integer.

You cannot compare a struct to an integer.

You can compare two structs, or two integers.

> The struct member is also an int (an array with int value)

This is false. The struct **contains** the integer array. So comparing them does not make sense.

Comment: I see it now, i can't compare the int with the array but the values of it by directly typing the variable i'm incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but judging by your error, this may be it:

```
void checkiffriends(){
for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j=0; j < 5; j++){
        if(ptr[i].m[j] == i){ //Change from ptr[i] to i
            printf("they are friends!", );
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to compare the value of m[j] with the value of the next struct. ex. m[1] compared to value of ptr[i+1] but now i see that it was just typing i+1. And that i can't compare it by typing the array representation.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed correctly you wanted to store struct member reference in variable m.

```
struct member{
   int num;
   char name[10];
   struct member* m; //correction
   int counter;
}ptr[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried (i+1) instead of ptr[i+1] in if condition.I think it is better way to avoid error.

Comment: Yes, typing (i+1) is definitely more correct than ptr[i+1]. Thanks for the advice.